# Modify server.ssl passwords on Spring Initialization

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, ssl, encryption

I have a spring application that uses `server.ssl.trust-store-password` and `server.ssl.key-store-password` properties. The app works fine, but now I want to encrypt this variables and decrypt this properties on Spring initialization.

So, at the end, my application.properties file will look like this:

```
server.ssl.key-store-password= encryptedPassword
server.ssl.trust-store-password= encryptedPassword
```

OR properties with different names if needed:

```
    key-store-encrypted-password= encryptedPassword
    trust-store-encrypted-password= encryptedPassword
```

What is the best way to do this?

What I've tried:

Creating a bean which will load first and set the system property, but for some reason Spring isn't using this properties.

```
@Order(Ordered.LOWEST_PRECEDENCE)
@Configuration
public class SSLEnvironmentProcessor
{
  @Autowired
  private ConfigurableEnvironment environment;

  @Bean
  public void loadProperties()
  {
    String valueKey = environment.getProperty("key-store-password-encrypted");
    String valueTrust = environment.getProperty("trust-store-password-encrypted");

    System.setProperty("server.ssl.key-store-password", decrypt(valueKey));
    System.setProperty("server.ssl.trust-store-password", decrypt(valueTrust));

  }
}
```

my application.properties:

```
key-store-password-encrypted=encryptedPASS
trust-store-password-encrypted=encryptedPASS
```

Error:

```
org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Failed to start bean 'webServerStartStop'; nested exception is org.springframework.boot.web.server.WebServerException: Unable to start embedded Tomcat server
org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:586) ~[spring-context-5.3.14.jar:5.3.14]
......
Caused by: org.springframework.boot.web.server.WebServerException: Unable to start embedded Tomcat server
    at 
    ... 19 more
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Protocol handler start failed
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.startInternal(Connector.java:1075) ~
    ... 19 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: keystore password was incorrect
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractJsseEndpoint.createSSLContext(AbstractJsseEndpoint.java:99) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar:9.0.56]
    at 
    ... 19 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: keystore password was incorrect
    at sun.security.pkcs12.PKCS12KeyStore.engineLoad(PKCS12KeyStore.java:2069) ~[?:1.8.0_311]
    at sun.security.provider.KeyStoreDelegator.engineLoad(KeyStoreDelegator.java:238) ~[?:1.8.0_311]
    ... 19 more
Caused by: java.security.UnrecoverableKeyException: failed to decrypt safe contents entry: javax.crypto.BadPaddingException: Given final block not properly padded. Such issues can arise if a bad key is used during decryption.
    at sun.security.pkcs12.PKCS12KeyStore.engineLoad(PKCS12KeyStore.java:2069)
```

Comment: I would think of adding these properties in a pipeline and using those via pipelinefile in your project. If you are familiar with Jenkins, then go with that.

Answer (score 0):

do it before the SpringApplication.run() in main:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {       
    String syskeystorePsw = "your password";
    System.setProperty("server.ssl.key-store-password", syskeystorePsw);
        
    SpringApplication.run(MySpringbootApplication.class, args);
}
```